# Java regex repeating capture groups

Tags: java, regex

Considering the following string: "${test.one}${test.two}" I would like my regex to return two matches, namely "test.one" and "test.two". To do that I have the following snippet:

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

```
public class RegexTester {

    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{((?:(?:[A-z]+(?:\\.[A-z0-9()\\[\\]\"]+)*)+|(?:\"[\\w/?.&=_\\-]*\")+)+)}+$");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String testString = "${test.one}${test.two}";

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testString);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have some other stuff in there as well, because I want this to also be a valid match ${test.one}${"hello"}.

So, basically, I just want it to match on anything inside of ${} as long as it either follows the format: `something.somethingelse` (alphanumeric only there) or `something.somethingElse()` or `"something inside of quotations"` (alphanumeric plus some other characters). I have the main regex working, or so I think, but when I run the code, it finds two groups,

${test.two}
test.two

I want the output to be

test.one
test.two

Comment: Something like `\$\{(\"[^\"]*\"|\w+(?:\(\))?(?:\.\w+(?:\(\))?)*)}`? See https://regex101.com/r/ILmyTj/1

Comment: And ignore group zero, which represents the entire expression.

Comment: I expect you meant `${test.one} test.two` for your third-to-last line.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - that basically works. I tweaked it a little. So, what was the issue with the regex that I had? I'd just like to understand what I was doing wrong so I can hopefully not repeat the same mistake :)

Comment: @cloudwalker I tried to explain, but your regex is too cumbersome. If you need more drill-through, please let me know.

Comment: Given the three acceptable formats you have given I assume you do not wish to match `${te.st.one}`, `${testone}` or `${"hel.lo"}`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, your regex main problem is that it matches only at the end of string, and you match many more chars that just letters with `[A-z]`. Your grouping also seem off.

If you load your regex at regex101, you [will see](https://regex101.com/r/iC41Ss/1) it matches

- `\$\{`
- `(` - start of a capturing group

  - `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group

    - `(?:[A-z]+` - start of a non-capturing group, and it matches 1+ chars between `A` and `z` ([your first mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970))

      - `(?:\.[A-z0-9()\[\]\"]+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of a `.` and then 1+ letters, digits, `(`, `)`, `[`, `]`, `"`, `\`, `^`, `_`, and a backtick
    - `)+` - repeat the non-capturing group 1 or more times
    - `|` - or
    - `(?:\"[\w/?.&=_\-]*\")+` - 1 or more occurrences of `"`, 0 or more word, `/`, `?`, `.`, `&`, `=`, `_`, `-` chars and then a `"`
    - `)+` - repeat the group pattern 1+ times
  - `)` - end of non-capturing group
- `}+` - 1+ `}` chars
- `$` - end of string.

To match any occurrence of your pattern inside a string, you need to use

```
\$\{(\"[^\"]*\"|\w+(?:\(\))?(?:\.\w+(?:\(\))?)*)}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ILmyTj/1), get Group 1 value after a match is found. Details:

- `\$\{` - a `${` substring
- `(\"[^\"]*\"|\w+(?:\(\))?(?:\.\w+(?:\(\))?)*)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `\"[^\"]*\"` - `"`, 0+ chars other than `"` and then a `"`
  - `|` - or
  - `\w+(?:\(\))?` - 1+ word chars and an optional `()` substring
  - `(?:\.\w+(?:\(\))?)*` - 0 or more repetitions of `.` and then 1+ word chars and an optional `()` substring
- `}` - a `}` char.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/llqrqQ):

```
String s = "${test.one}${test.two}\n${test.one}${test.two()}\n${test.one}${\"hello\"}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(\"[^\"]*\"|\\w+(?:\\(\\))?(?:\\.\\w+(?:\\(\\))?)*)}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
}
```

Output:

```
test.one
test.two
test.one
test.two()
test.one
"hello"
```

Comment: Thank you, that was super helpful! I've been trying to get into regex stuff more here lately as it is something that I do not have a ton of experience with in the past, and it's definitely been a rocky start :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regular expression

```
(?<=\$\{")[a-z]+(?="\})|(?<=\$\{)[a-z]+\.[a-z]+(?:\(\))?(?=\})
```

which has no capture groups. The characters classes `[a-z]` can be modified as required provided they do not include a double-quote, period or right brace.

[Demo](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyydgg94nr)

Java's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<=\$\{")  # match '${"' in a positive lookbehind
[a-z]+      # match 1+ lowercase letters 
(?="\})     # match '"}' in a positive lookahead
|           # or 
(?<=\$\{)   # match '${' in a positive lookbehind
[a-z]+      # match 1+ lowercase letters 
\.[a-z]+    # match '.' followed by 1+ lowercase letters
(?:\(\))?   # optionally match `()`
(?=\})      # match '}' in a positive lookahead
```